# Python keras : to_categorical indexerror

Tags: python, keras

i want to apply to_categorical for obtain a matrix of my labels (i have just 2 classes), here is my code :

```
  for i in range(df.text.shape[0]):

      classess.append(df.classe[i])

  labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(classess),num_classes = 2)
```

and the error is :

```
 index -9223372036854775808 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: What values are you appending to that array? It should be 0 or 1 for two classes.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes it is just 0 and 1

Comment: Then you need to find out where the -9223372036854775808 is coming from.